# Force SynchronizationContext to post to main thread in console app

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I have a .NET Core console app that uses EF Core. Most of the heavy lifting is done in a few async methods and then I update my EF context from a continuation. Unfortunately EF gets a bit testy when you try to use the DbContext from multiple threads so I've been trying to get my continuations to run in the same thread that the context was created in (Thread 1 / main thread in this case).

Here is a simple sample class to illustrate the approach I'm trying to take and I think I'm close but I'm missing some critical piece because the continuations keep running in the same thread as the task in the `DoGreeting` method.

```cs
public class Worker
    {

        private static readonly MyContext _ctx = new MyContext();

        public void Run()
        {

            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(_ctx);
            Console.WriteLine($"Synchronization context set in thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            DoGreeting("Bob").Wait();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public async Task DoGreeting(string Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DoGreeting was called from thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await Task.Run(() => { SayHi(Name); });
            SayGoodbye(Name);
        }

        public void SayHi(string Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {Name} from thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        public void SayGoodbye(string Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Goodbye {Name} from thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        private class MyContext : SynchronizationContext
        {
            public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Post called from thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                d(state);
            }
        }
    }
```

My gut tells me that the problem is in the `Post` method of my custom synchronization context because it's being called from the same thread that the task was running on and I haven't told it that it needs to run back on the main thread. I was under the false assumption that since the context was instantiated in thread 1 then anything it posts would also run there. I think this is where I'm stuck and I'm not sure the best approach so advice appreciated.

I know there are different approaches to running EF Core in an Async app but most of those solutions are tailored for ASP.NET Core or other applications that use DI. My app, however, is a console app with no DI. EF Core advice in console apps is certainly welcome (and my solve my issue) but I *would* also like to know how to force a continuation to run back on the main thread in case I come across this again in the future.

Thanks!!

Comment: .NET Core doesn't have synchronization context and now everything works like with ```.ConfigureAwait(false)``` in .NET Framework.

EDIT: It was removed only from ASP.NET

Comment: There is no "main thread". Console applications are MTA by default (but don't just change the default). Stop oversharing your dbcontexts instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no conceptual difference between DI design in a console app or a web app because all you need to get this set up is registration phase and resolution phase which in case of an ASP.NET Core or MVC is done by the infrastructure while in case of a console app you should do it manually. I don't know the structure of your app and how many flows it's supposed to serve but the best practice for EF is to create separate context per flow, in case of web app a flow is a request handling, in case of WPF or Win Forms it can be a form, etc (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime) for more details). So consider follow these recommendations in your application.

As for the second question if it's related to a console application again, you need to organize some sort of message pump in your `Program.Main` method or a method called by it. The message pump is supposed to read messages from some shared queue, say based on top of `BlockingCollection` for safety and execute their handlers. The `Post` method in your custom synchronization context then should merely put the messages into the queue and nothing more (which fits the "fire and forget" semantic) while real execution should happen inside the main message pump. If you need exception handling you'll have to consider to implement synchronous `Send` method to obtain the exceptions from say another completion queue once an execution is completed.